# gaussian mixture model probability matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, gaussian, probability-theory, mixture-model

I have a data of dimension 50x100000. (100000 features, each has a dimension of 50).

I would like to fit a gaussian mixture model using this data. I used the following code.

```
               obj = gmdistribution.fit(X',3);
```

What I need is when I give a new data Y I should be able to get the likelihood probabilities $p(Y|\theta)$, where $\theta$ are the gaussing mixture model parameters.

I used the following code to get the probability values.

```
               P = pdf(obj,X');
```

But I am getting very low values all are about 0. Whay it is happning? How can i get the appropreate probability values?

Comment: When you say that your data is dimension 50x100000, do you mean that you've got 100000 vectors of length 50, and that you're looking for a mixture of multivariate normal distributions, i.e. each distribution in the mixture is a multivariate normal distribution for a vector of length 50?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one dimension, the maximum value of the pdf of the Gaussian distribution is 1/sqrt(2*PI).  So in 50 dimensions, the maximum value is going to be 1/(sqrt(2*PI)^50) which is around 1E-20.  So the values of the pdf are all going to be of that order of magnitude, or smaller.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. what is PI here? I am planning to build a classifier to reject outliers from the probability values. I am learning this distribution based on one class of data. In my case how can I build a classifier based on the probability values?

Comment: PI is 3.14159 etc.  sqrt is the square-root function.  I *think* that I've probably answered your original question, so if you agree, you might consider flagging this answer as useful and/or accepted.  If you post another question related to how to build your classifier then I'll definitely have a look and post an answer to your new question if I can.  FYI, I always take a look at all questions that have the `probability` tag.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113387/outlier-detection-based-on-gaussian-mixture-model looking for your reply. :-)